# Is there a way, to avoid authenticate dialog on snap install / remove?

Tags: snap

I have rather large setup scripts for fresh Ubuntu-MATE machines (silent install, unattended install...), and I would like to get rid of this UI authentication dialog, i.e. when I do

```
snap remove --purge ubuntu-mate-welcome
```

(providing the password in a parameter, stdin-pipe or otherwise is perfectly fine for me, they'll be changed later again anyway)...

[image]

Comment: To avoid UI dialog, commands requiring privilege escalation shall be prefixed by `sudo`, like: `sudo snap remove --purge ubuntu-mate-welcome`. That will however ask for the user password at least the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation happens because the operation you are executing (`snap remove`) requires to be executed as superuser `root`. You have to run such commands as `sudo <command>`. That will however ask for the user password at least the first time.

According to `sudo` [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), the `-S` option allows to provide the password as `stdin`:

> **-S** The **-S** (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

If security is not an issue, you can do the following:

```
echo -e '<password>\n' | sudo -S <command>
```